# How can I search for the most similar entry using Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How can I search effectively for information in a database, being able to handle both spelling errors and longer texts, unlike `icontains` and trigram similarity?

## Info

Language: Python 3.9.7
Platform: Django 3.2.8
Database: PostgreSQL 14.1

## Goal

Searching effectively for information in a database by being able to handle both spelling errors and longer texts.

There are many ways I can query for information in a database, mine being PostgreSQL, such as `__contains`, `__icontains`, `unnaccent__icontains`, `__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar`, and so on. Though these are very handy, none of these helped my really reach the goal I have in mind: searching for the *most* similar entry. Trigram similarity got pretty close, but it no longer worked for longer strings. Is there any operation that can get the closest value, also working for longer strings?

Here is the problem I'm facing:
In my website, I want a person to be able to search for books. I'm using trigram similarity. Searching for `lord` and `lord of` yields no results, while `lord of the`, `lord of the rings`, and `lord of the rings: fellowship of the ring` gives the correct results.

I don't like this! People who might not want to type all of that text wouldn't do it, they'd probably just type `lord` or something like that. I could just use `__contains` or `__icontains`, but I want to handle spelling mistakes.

How do I handle both of them?

## Thoughts & Ideas

1. I've used `SpaCy` before, but that was only for my machine learning projects. Should I use that?
2. If there is no available answer, I think I'm going to have to make one on my own.

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: Have you tried  trigrams word similarity operators?  such as `<->>`?

Comment: @jjanes, I have updated my post to include version details.

Comment: I didn't understand, what's a trigram word similarity operator?

Comment: It was added to django in 4.0

Comment: oh... sorry, but I'm not using 4, 3.2 is where I am